# Implementing this Interface Properly

Tags: java, gwt, interface

I'm trying to implement this interface properly:

```
public interface OccupancyGrid {

    public Grid  grid();
}
```

Then I have a class which implements it:

```
    public class OccupancyCheckView implements OccupancyGrid{

    private Grid myGrid = new Grid(17,17);

    @Override
    public Grid grid() {

        return myGrid;
    }

    public main_(){
        createResultGrid("Test Grid");
                //More code below which changes the properties of 'myGrid'
    }
```

Then I have a class which is trying to call upon the above interface:

```
public class TestOccupanciesPanel
{
    private VerticalPanel mainPanel_;

        OccupancyGrid myGrid = new OccupancyCheckView();

    //This is where I trip up
        mainPanel_.add(myGrid);
```

I've seen elsewhere in the code I'm editing the user of interfaces very cleanly but without going about it in the way I've done above, it seems much cleaner. The code simply does something like:

```
OccupancyCheckView.class
```

Can you help me out and give me some tips?

Comment: This question is very unclear. What about `myGrid.main_()`? It isn't clear what role the interface has here.

Comment: I added the edited code in

Comment: And yes - I've edited the correction in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either call your `createResultGrid` method in the constructor:

```
public OccupancyCheckView() {
     myGrid = new Grid(17,17);
     createResultGrid("Test Grid");
}
```

With this approach, the `createResultGrid` method will be executed on object creation - if you have some heavy code there, it might slow the program.

Or use lazy initialisation:

```
private boolean resultGridCreated = false;

@Override
public Grid grid() {
    if(!resultGridCreated) {
        createResultGrid("Test Grid");
        resultGridCreated = true;
    }
    return myGrid;
}
```

With this approach, the grid initialisation will be done the first time when `grid()` is being called.

Comment: So in otherwords, remove `main_(){` and replace it with `OccupancyCheckView() {` ?

Comment: In otherwords, yes :-) as I see it, you are trying to push instantiation logic in a separate method - simply use a constructor instead.

Comment: OK I understand that now. The only problem is when I try to add the Grid myGrid object in my TestOccupancyPanel, it says I need to cast it as a Widget which breaks my code and I don't think that's quite right. Do you know how I extract the object from it?

Comment: Ahh figured it out now, I need to access the object inside that class.... Thanks for getting me back on track!